# How to use a better way to initialize the static Google's LoadingCache in spring

Tags: spring

I'm using Google's LoadingCache in spring. Due to some needs, I have to create new bean replace old during runtime. In order not to lose all the cache, I must make LoadingCache static. Now i use ApplicationRunner to  init LoadingCache and wondering if there is a better way, such as adding final to LoadingCache, do not implement the ApplicationRunner interface to initialize

```
@Component
public class Test implements ApplicationRunner {
    private static LoadingCache<String, String> CACHE;
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()  
                .maximumSize(100)     
                .expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build(
                        new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String load(@NotNull String id) {
                                //private method in bean
                                return loadVal(id);                               
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    private String loadVal(String id) {
    //select database
        return "";
    }
}
```